# How to vectorize nested for loop for operations on different indices of the same matrix/array?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I've been trying to vectorize a for loop in Matlab because it bottlenecks the whole program but I have no clue about how to do it when iterating on different rows or columns of a single matrix inside of the loop. Here's the code :

```
// X is an n*k matrix, W is n*n
// W(i,j) stores the norm of the vector resulting from subtracting
// the j-th line of X from its i-th line.
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        W(i,j) = norm(X(i,:) - X(j,:))
    end
end
```

## Edit :

I chose Luis Mendo's answer as it was the most convenient for me and the one that's closer to the mathematical concept behind my algorithm, yet all three answers were correct and I'd advise to use the one that's the most convenient depending on which Matlab Toolboxes you have or the way you want to code.

I also noticed that the common point of all answers was to use a different format, for example : using an array that would store the indices, reshaping current arrays, using one more dimension...
So I think that's the right thing to explore if you have a similar problem.

Comment: Have you already tried to vectorise the inner loop only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have the Statistics Toolbox, use [`pdist`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html):

  ```
  W = squareform(pdist(X));
  ```
- No toolbox: good old [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

  ```
  W = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, permute(X, [1 3 2]), permute(X, [3 1 2])).^2, 3));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Using combinatory:

```
% sample data
X = randi(9,5,4);
n = size(X,1);

% row index combinations
combIdx = combvec(1:n,1:n);
% difference between row combinations
D = X(combIdx(1,:),:)-X(combIdx(2,:),:);
% norm of each row
W = diag(sqrt(D*D'));
% reshape
W = reshape(W,n,[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution that may be more efficient for big matrices.

For Matlab >=R2016 you can simple use

```
W = sqrt(sum(abs(reshape(X,n,1,k) - reshape(X,1,n,k)).^2,3))
```

(if your array is real-valued you can also skip the abs). For earlier versions of Matlab you need to add some repmat magic, namely:

```
W = sqrt(sum(abs(repmat(reshape(X,n,1,k),[1,n,1]) - repmat(reshape(X,1,n,k),[n,1,1])).^2,3));
```

P.S.: R2017b might make it even more convenient, at least the [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/relnotes/relnotes_pr.pdf) mention a function called `vecnorm` that could replace the somewhat ugly `sqrt(sum(abs(.).^2)))` thing. But the documentation is not up yet so I don't know what exactly it will do. "